# System.OutOfMemoryException when running multiple CROSS JOINs

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert the Cartesian product of 5 tables into 6th table (call it A). The tables (call them B, C, D, E, F) have 10 and 10,000 records, and the total records returned by the Cartesian product should be about 500,000 (and yes I do need all of them in table A). The following should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT * FROM B CROSS JOIN C CROSS JOIN D CROSS JOIN E CROSS JOIN F
```

However upon execution SQL throws a System.OutOfMemoryException. I know SQL management studio inherently works with only 2GB of memory on a 32 bit platform, so I'm sure that is filling up and causing the error. How can the memory be cleared as records are inserted so the code will complete?

Comment: *Management studio* shouldn't be running out of memory. SQL Server might.. can you post the exact error you get?

Comment: @ Blorgbeard: actually that's incorrect. More likely SSMS runs out of memory...If  you have a SQL server 'server' that runs out of memory, it either has config issues or insufficient physical memory to begin with

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The exact error is 'An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Comment: It's certainly not the 'server' running out of memory. I'm almost certain it is SSMS.

Comment: SSMS is only going to run out of memory if you are displaying results in it.....

Comment: Output to text file or csv instead of the query window may help if it is the local ssms app.